# Check that $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to check whether $\sqrt{z}$ is an analytic function using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If we let $z = x+iy$, then we have $$\sqrt{x+iy}$$ What are the values of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$?

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{z}$ when $z$ is complex and not real positive?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your function maps $z=re^{i\theta} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ depending on the branch you choose. Just use the polar form of the CR equations from here.

Comment: What if we have $\sqrt{z^2 - a^2}$? How would we convert this to polar?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rewrite to polar coordinates first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/666481)

Comment: @JohnMarkPerry I know it's not a full answer, and it's awfully short, but don't come here and tell me it's not a valid hint.

Comment: i have seen longer comments, its true

Comment: @JohnMarkPerry But it is not a critique, and not a request for clarification, and to someone who understands it, it clearly points towards the solution, so what your first comment is trying to say is beyond me. Also, if I had posted this as a comment, I would've run the risk of someone telling me not to answer a question in the comments. Did's comment above is definitely a critique / request for information, so it belongs there. My answer is meant to help the OP solve his problem, which means posting it as an answer is a valid option, even though it's only six words.